# No missions available after dying

Tags: just-cause-2

The map in Just Cause 2 shows only villages, discovered and undiscovered locations. The map legend shows all the location icons as active/visible.

On starting a new game, I died quickly at the casino right after being dropped off by the girlfriend on the motorcycle. The casino doesn't have any obvious mission markers, I think (nothing obvious). I've gone and completed the casino at 100%, and done 5 hours worth of exploring and chaos. I've unlocked lots of Black Market items, but haven't yet been introduced to anything about Black Market. I've got a good amount of Chaos racked up, but of the 4 progress bars, only Black Market is effected. The other 3 have yet to increase their value.

When I respawn, it's always at the house where you got on the motorbike at the beginning of the game. Again, there are no obvious clues at the house on what to do.

Does this sound normal? Can you suggest how to start proper missions? Hoping I haven't got a subtle glitch or anything. The game hasn't crashed at all. Latest version Was downloaded by Xbox Live.

Comment: I have the same issue on the PC. I got the house, did a faction mission, took over the port, then tried a flying race mission. After I've died, I've created 40,000 worth of chaos, but only the Black Market progress bar has progressed, and I cannot call the Black Market helicopter. If I press 4, then E nothing happens. There are no missions showing up on the map at all. I believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've generated enough chaos to unlock another "agency", "faction" or "stronghold" mission a new mission icon (grey star for agency, yellow/red/? for factions) should show up the map.  You can start the mission by going to that location and activating the mission (usually by pressing the yellow "Y" button at a roadside kiosk looking thing).

The progress bar is used to show how much chaos you need to earn to unlock the next mission, but is only "active" if you've already played through all the open missions in that category.

Your bars aren't active b/c you've already earned enough chaos to unlock a bunch of missions in each category that you haven't played yet (you're map should have a bunch of stars on it).  Once you play through all of the unlocked missions in a particular category it should activate again to show you how much more you need to unlock the next mission.

Answer (score 2):

On the PC version, you jump out of the Casino skywalk with Blaine, go through a car chase and end up at Blaine's house where he gives you a blackmarket beacon. Three "faction" headquarters are shown on your map and you can visit all of them to unlock new missions.